# Can't replace default RequestMappingHandlerMapping properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have difficulties with a simple Spring Boot configuration. One of the beans is being instantiated twice and the config overall looks non-optimal, especially in adding interceptors part (although it works fine).

Intro:

1. ApiHandlerMapping class inherits RequestMappingHandlerMapping. Some of the logic relies on .getHandlerMethods() call on this bean.
2. CustomResourceHandler implements HandlerInterceptor interface.

Config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(
        customResourceHandler(apiHandlerMapping(dataProvider(apiProperties()), apiProperties()),
        apiProperties()));
    }

        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties
    public ApiProperties apiProperties() {
        return new ApiProperties();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DataProvider dataProvider(ApiProperties apiProperties) {
        return new DataProvider(apiProperties);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiHandlerMapping apiHandlerMapping(DataProvider dataProvider, ApiProperties apiProperties) {
        return new ApiVersionHandlerMapping(dataProvider, apiProperties);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CustomResourceHandler customResourceHandler(ApiHandlerMapping apiHandlerMapping,
                                                               ApiProperties apiProperties) {
        return new CustomResourceHandler(apiHandlerMapping, apiProperties);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcRegistrations apiVersions(DataProvider dataProvider, ApiProperties apiProperties) {
        return new WebMvcRegistrations() {
            @Override
            public RequestMappingHandlerMapping getRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
                return new ApiVersionHandlerMapping(dataProvider, apiProperties);
            }
        };
    }
```

Is there a chance to refactor this config to instantiate ApiHandlerMapping only once and have a neat and nice interceptor injection?
Is it a better option to extend DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration and override RequestMappingHandlerMapping there to not to implement WebMvcConfigurer?

ApiVersionHandlerMapping is being instantiated at least 2 times here, even though everything works fine.
I've tried to eliminate one of the instantiation points by:

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcRegistrations apiVersions(ApiHandlerMapping apiHandlerMapping) {
        return new WebMvcRegistrations() {
            @Override
            public RequestMappingHandlerMapping getRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
                return apiHandlerMapping;
            }
        };
    }
```

, but got "ambiguous handler methods mapping" error for each of the test endpoints, which are basically "/test-url/a", "/test-url/b", so they don't intersect.

Comment: You register it twice yourself. Either ditch the `@Bean` method or remove the `WebMmcRegistrations`. You don't need both.